# How to port this query from MySQL to Oracle

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I have a mysql query and I'm trying to port it to oracle DB.

```
select * from Employees e inner join People p on e.person_id=p.id 
    where LOWER(`first_name`) like LOWER(?) 
          and LOWER(`last_name`) like LOWER(?)
```

But Oracle doesn't like the backticks.  I've tried double quotes according to their docs:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12151_01/doc.150/e12155/oracle_mysql_compared.htm

But no dice.  How do I port that rather simple query to Oracle SQL?

Comment: @OldProgrammer's right. In Oracle identifiers default to UPPER_CASE, but double-quoting an identifier means 'use the identifier "exactly_Like_THIS_casewise"'). I suspect that in your Oracle tables all the column names are in upper case, although you can refer to them using lower_case_names; the lower-case names will be converted to UPPER_CASE behind the scenes by the database. However if you specify the column as "lower_case" in double quotes then the actual column name must be in lower case or it won't be found. Basic rule: NEVER EVER EVER use lower or mixed case identifiers in Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming first_name, last_name are columns of Employees, just remove the quotes (ticks).  There is no need for that in Oracle.

```
select * from Employees e inner join People p on e.person_id=p.id 
    where LOWER(first_name) like LOWER(?) 
          and LOWER(last_name) like LOWER(?)
```

Comment: This actually is portable to mysql as well.  Thanks!